# Позиционирование div при добавление информации | Выход его за экран

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том, что если добавлять элементы ITEM, то некоторые из них не будет видно. Они будут скрыты за экраном.

Код:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
h3,
p,
a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.downloads {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px;
  max-width: 45.2vw;
  height: 100%;
}

.downloads:after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

.downloads>h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -2%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 2%);
  width: 10vw;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(247, 52, 124) 0%, rgb(255, 89, 74) 100%);
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 10px 20px -8px #2d2d2d;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/*----------------------------------------- Button -----------------------------------------*/

.install>a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(247, 52, 124) 0%, rgb(255, 89, 74) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 70%;
  transition: .25s;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.install>a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .25s;
}

.install>a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  width: calc(100% + 8px);
  height: calc(100% + 8px);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(247, 52, 124) 0%, rgb(255, 89, 74) 100%);
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .25s;
}

.install>a:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .25s;
}

.install>a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transition: .25s;
}


/*----------------------------------------- Button -----------------------------------------*/


/*------------------------------------------ Item ------------------------------------------*/

.item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 20vw;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin: 25px;
  transition: .15s;
}

.item:hover:before {
  box-shadow: 1px 10px 20px -8px #2d2d2d;
  transition: .25s;
}

.item:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: -2;
  transition: .25s;
}

.item:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  width: calc(100% + 8px);
  height: calc(100% + 8px);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(247, 52, 124) 0%, rgb(255, 89, 74) 100%);
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: -2;
  transition: .25s;
}

.item:nth-child(2n):before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 89, 74) 0%, rgb(247, 52, 124) 100%);
}

.item:nth-child(2n)>.txt {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 89, 74) 0%, rgb(247, 52, 124) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}


/*------------------------------------------ Item ------------------------------------------*/


/*------------------------------------------ Img ------------------------------------------*/

.img>img {
  max-width: 50%;
  border-radius: 30px;
}


/*------------------------------------------ Img ------------------------------------------*/


/*------------------------------------------ TxT ------------------------------------------*/

.txt {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(247, 52, 124) 0%, rgb(255, 89, 74) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}


/*------------------------------------------ TxT ------------------------------------------*/


/*----------------------------------------- Wrap -----------------------------------------*/

.warp {
  width: 50vw;
}


/*----------------------------------------- Wrap -----------------------------------------*/


/*---------------------------------------- Footer ----------------------------------------*/

footer {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(247, 52, 124) 0%, rgb(255, 89, 74) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  margin: 15px;
}

footer>p>a {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(247, 52, 124) 0%, rgb(255, 89, 74) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/*---------------------------------------- Footer ----------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="downloads">
    <h2>Загрузки</h2>
    <div class="warp">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="../img/script.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="txt">
          <h3>Скрипт Загрузок</h3>
          <p>Это скрипт который вы видети перед собой</p>
          <h6>Индификатор загрузки: 0</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="install">
          <a href="files/sc-downloads.rar" download="">Устоновить</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="../img/script.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="txt">
          <h3>Скрипт Загрузок</h3>
          <p>Это скрипт который вы видети перед собой</p>
          <h6>Индификатор загрузки: 1</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="install">
          <a href="files/sc-downloads.rar" download="">Устоновить</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="../img/script.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="txt">
          <h3>Скрипт Загрузок</h3>
          <p>Это скрипт который вы видети перед собой</p>
          <h6>Индификатор загрузки: 2</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="install">
          <a href="files/sc-downloads.rar" download="">Устоновить</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="../img/script.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="txt">
          <h3>Скрипт Загрузок</h3>
          <p>Это скрипт который вы видети перед собой</p>
          <h6>Индификатор загрузки: 3</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="install">
          <a href="files/sc-downloads.rar" download="">Устоновить</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <p>Внимание! Все права защищены! © <a href="http://vk.me/dskoper">MrSkoper</a>, 2018</p>
</footer>
```

Желательный результат:

[image: Изображение]

Выделенные квадраты должны быть темнее.

Comment: Надо убирать абсолютное позиционирование у вашей обертки и центрировать методом margin:0 auto;

Comment: Появилась вторая проблема [Изображение](http://prntscr.com/j6qac3)

Comment: А обязательно все таким громким начертанием писать, я думаю люди не слепые

Comment: Нужно очистить поток, (ваша обертка):after{display:table;content:''; clear:both}

Comment: После применение сломался весь дизайн. [Было](https://prnt.sc/j6qac3) -> [Стало](http://prntscr.com/j6qdaf)

Comment: так что? поможете

Comment: @MrSkoper  а как это должно выгдядеть ?

Comment: Примерно вот так -> [Пример](http://prntscr.com/j6qng5). Только задний цвет должен потемнее быть и див должен быть белым

Comment: Спасибо! Спасибо!

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, Ну так что?

Comment: \\\ Спасибо всем ///

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил. Осталось адаптировать.

Кому нужен код:

*Желательно открыть на новой странице*

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #f2f2f2f2;
}

.downloads h1,
.downloads h2,
.downloads h3,
.downloads h4,
.downloads h5,
.downloads h6,
.downloads h3,
.downloads p,
.downloads a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.downloads img {
  max-width: 260px;
}

.downloads {
  margin: 50px auto;
  max-width: 50vw;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.downloads>h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3f92 1%, #ff4242 100%);
  box-shadow: 1px 10px 20px -8px #2d2d2d;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.download {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  max-width: calc((20vw + 20vw) + 100.5px);
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.download .item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 20vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.download .item::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5%;
  left: 1.5%;
  width: 97%;
  height: 97%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: white;
  z-index: -3;
}

.download .item::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3f92 1%, #ff4242 100%);
  z-index: -4;
  transition: .25s;
}

.download .item:nth-child(2n)::after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff4242 1%, #ff3f92 100%);
}

.download .item:hover::after {
  box-shadow: 1px 10px 20px -8px #2d2d2d;
  transition: .25s;
}

.download .item img {
  max-width: 150px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.download .item h1,
.download .item h2,
.download .item h3,
.download .item h4,
.download .item h5,
.download .item h6,
.download .item p {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3f92 1%, #ff4242 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.download .item:nth-child(2n) h1,
.download .item:nth-child(2n) h2,
.download .item:nth-child(2n) h3,
.download .item:nth-child(2n) h4,
.download .item:nth-child(2n) h5,
.download .item:nth-child(2n) h6,
.download .item:nth-child(2n) p {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff4242 1%, #ff3f92 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.download .item .txt {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.download .item .install a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3f92 1%, #ff4242 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: .25s;
}

.download .item:nth-child(2n) .install a {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3f92 1%, #ff4242 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.download .item .install a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 2%;
  width: 96%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: white;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .25s;
}

.download .item .install a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3f92 1%, #ff4242 100%);
  z-index: -2;
}

.download .item:nth-child(2n) .install a::after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff4242 1%, #ff3f92 100%);
}

.download .item .install a:hover {
  background: white;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.download .item .install a:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .25s;
}

.dw-copyright {
  width: 50vw;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.dw-copyright p,
.dw-copyright a {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

.dw-copyright p:hover,
.dw-copyright a:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff4242 1%, #ff3f92 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="downloads">
    <h2>Загрузки</h2>
    <div class="download">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="../img/script.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="txt">
          <h3>Скрипт Загрузок</h3>
          <p>Это скрипт который вы видети перед собой</p>
          <h6>Индификатор загрузки: 0</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="install">
          <a href="files/sc-downloads.rar" download>Устоновить</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="../img/script.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="txt">
          <h3>Скрипт Загрузок</h3>
          <p>Это скрипт который вы видети перед собой</p>
          <h6>Индификатор загрузки: 1</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="install">
          <a href="files/sc-downloads.rar" download>Устоновить</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="../img/script.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="txt">
          <h3>Скрипт Загрузок</h3>
          <p>Это скрипт который вы видети перед собой</p>
          <h6>Индификатор загрузки: 2</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="install">
          <a href="files/sc-downloads.rar" download>Устоновить</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="../img/script.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="txt">
          <h3>Скрипт Загрузок</h3>
          <p>Это скрипт который вы видети перед собой</p>
          <h6>Индификатор загрузки: 3</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="install">
          <a href="files/sc-downloads.rar" download>Устоновить</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <div class="dw-copyright">
    <p>Внимание! Все права защищены! © <a href="http://vk.me/dskoper">MrSkoper</a>, 2018</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Может поставите положительно количество балов этому вопросу?

Comment: Не поставлю, у вас "Установить" через О — "Устоновить":)